# Line breaks produce Text nodes in DOMDocument - how should I handle this

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm using php's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) library and read an XML string with [loadXML](https://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadxml.php). I am then iterating over the childs of a node tagged "Info" with this code:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GAEB xmlns="http://www.gaeb.de/GAEB_DA_XML/DA31/3.2">
 <Info>
  <Version>3.2</Version>
  <VersDate>2013-10</VersDate>
  <Date>2014-10-10</Date>
  <Time>12:28:28</Time>
  <ProgSystem>GAEB Zertifizierung</ProgSystem>
  <ProgName>BVBS</ProgName>
 </Info>
</GAEB>'
);

$Info = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Info");

foreach ($Info as $element) {
    echo "[". $element->nodeName. "]";
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo "[" . $node->nodeName . "]";
        echo  $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

This node  has 6 childs, however the iteration has 13 runs. That's because there is whitespace characters that interpreted as [Text nodes](https://www.php.net/manual/de/dom.constants.php). If I look at each nodes `$node->nodeType` it shows `1` for the 6 real childs and `3` for the 7 childs which contents are `\n`. The question is now, how am I supposed to deal with it? Is it ok that the DOMDocument contains those text nodes and I should "continue" over them with something like `if($node->nodeType===3) continue` or would I try to delete those whitespaces earlier when loading the xml. Just removing the `\n` from the input xml doesn't work because then spaces between the nodes (e.g. `>   <`) are interpreted as Text nodes.

### sample file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GAEB xmlns="http://www.gaeb.de/GAEB_DA_XML/DA31/3.2">
 <Info>
  <Version>3.2</Version>
  <VersDate>2013-10</VersDate>
  <Date>2014-10-10</Date>
  <Time>12:28:28</Time>
  <ProgSystem>GAEB Zertifizierung</ProgSystem>
  <ProgName>BVBS</ProgName>
 </Info>
</GAEB>
```

Comment: Could you show an example XML content? Generally, those text nodes are present in any xml document and element. You should probably use DOMXPath to filter specific elements https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Thanks, this is already helpful. I tend then to believe it is ok, that the whitespae characters are transformed to Text nodes and will leave the input untouched. Composing the query with xPath has a steep learning curve, but I will get it.

Comment: Yeah, you could also try to filter only `$node->nodeType==1` if you are looking for any tag Node.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your problem. No indication how `$doc` was created in your code.

Comment: You may find that SimpleXML makes this easier as it doesn't consider a lot of the whitespace used to format XML documents as relevant.  It is more aimed at data processing and so is less flexible, but easier to work with (hence the name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blank nodes can be ignored with the [`LIBXML_NOBLANKS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-noblanks) option as follows:

```
$doc->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```